# regex starting with 07 and having 10 or 12 digits

Tags: regex

I have tried to create such a regex but I don't know how to make it start with 07

Conditions:

- 10 or 12 digits
- starts with 07
- third digit is 2, 3 or 7

Valid matches

```
0732121212
072212121212
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you've already tried, so we don't assume you're just here because you're too lazy to look it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
^07[237][0-9]{7}([0-9]{2})?$
```

Comment: set begin ^ and end $ also

Comment: `...[0-9]{7}([0-9]{2})?` (10 or 12, not between 10 and 12)

Comment: I'd use `\d` rather than `[0-9]`

Comment: So would I, but I have no idea what regex engine is in use, so I went with the LCD.

Comment: I'd stick with `[0-9]` as it highlights the difference to the other positions.

Answer (score 0):

`07[237][0-9]{7,9}` should do what you want. 07 is a literal. In order for a string to be accepted it must start with exactly 07. After that we have a group for the third digit which includes the desired values ( 2, 3, and 7 ), you must have exactly one digit from that set. After that have another group [0-9], the set of all possible digits, and {7,9} denotes that you can have 7 or 9 digits in the set [0-9].

Comment: 10 or 12 digits, not 10 or 11 or 12 digits.